# Using Whitenoise but still can not serve static files

Tags: django, product, whitenoise

I'm trying to serve static files in my product review website, and I'm using Whitenoise, but It didn't work (can not find the files in /static) (when I test on local with DEFAULT = False, it still works)

I've tried to config wsgi file instead of using whitenoise middleware

This is my some code in my settings file to serve static.

```
DEBUG = False

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    ...
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'djangobower.finders.BowerFinder',
)
```

Can you show me how to fix it? Pardon for my English

I tried to config the settings again:

```
DEBUG = False

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    ...
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
# I don't have STATICFILES_DIRS, is it wrong?
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage"
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'djangobower.finders.BowerFinder',
)
```

But it still can not serve static files

Comment: if the results are different when you test on your local machine, can you share the nginx/Apache configuration to see if there are any problems that could interfere?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're missing is the `STATICFILES_STORAGE`. This is my `settings.py` related configuration.

```py
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage"
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]
```

Comment: Can you show me the line that you config ALLOW_HOST, I'm trying to put staticfiles_storage but it returns the code 500, 400. And when I run collectstatic (I deleted all static and staticfiles files) it returns with error can not find the static directory (code is the same as you). Thank you

Comment: I'm allowing everything on my ALLOWED_HOSTS because it's a test project. I've edited my answer.

Comment: I've tried it but when I launch it on review website, it return error 500, and when I remove the staticfiles_storage, it can open website again (but can not load static files). Can you tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: I solved the error 500 by using ```STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage"``` and it works but still can not load static files

Comment: Cool. This was the first time I used that so, don't know exactly the in/outs of this package

Comment: So please see my updated config files, and can you give me some advise, I spent whole morning for that :<

Comment: You should try to add `STATICFILES_DIRS` as I've added in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I followed the below configuration settings to resolve the issue.

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['testnewapp.herokuapp.com']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'phonenumber_field',
    'django_extensions',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    ...
]

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

# Whitenoise Storage Class  - Apply compression but don’t want the caching behaviour
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage'

# Comment the below line
# django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

### Things to Remember

1. Make sure you’re using the static template tag to refer to your static files, rather that writing the URL directly. For example:

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static "images/error.jpg" %}" alt="OOps!" />

<!-- DON'T WRITE THIS -->
<img src="/static/images/error.jpg" alt="OOps!" />
```

2. If you get an error message with collectstatic, simply disable it by instructing Heroku to ignore running the manage.py collecstatic command during the deployment process.

## But if you need to use WhiteNoise with any WSGI application

- You need to wrap your existing WSGI application in a WhiteNoise instance and tell it where to find your static files. For example:

```
from my_project import MyWSGIApp

application = MyWSGIApp()
application = WhiteNoise(application, root='/path/to/static/files')
application.add_files('/path/to/more/static/files', prefix='more-files/')
```

### Note

#### These instructions apply to any WSGI application. However, for Django applications you would be better off using the WhiteNoiseMiddleware class which makes integration easier.

### #

http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/base.html